# Change project package name

Tags: android, android-studio

There are already questions on this but I would like to learn  current preffered / best approach for changing the package name in Android Studio. I don't want to mess things up trying to change it. I am using Android Studio version 1.5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio Rename Package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To rename the package name in Android studio,

Click on the setting icon in the project section and untick the **Compact empty Middle Packages**,

after that the package will split into multiple folder names,

then right click on the folder you need to change the name, 
click on refactor-> **Rename**-> Type the name you want to change in -> Do refactor -> Refactor Directory Working for me

[image]

[image]

Comment: I completed these steps , now I get an error saying 'can't find symbol R'

Comment: try rebuilding the project. Build -> Rebuild Project.... Still if not work Try Build -> Clean Project...... hope it will solve but if that also not work then let me know if  still this error

Comment: if still you see that error Try this "Tools" -> "Android" -> "Sync Project with Gradle Files"